# Entity Framework Find vs. Where

Tags: .net, performance, entity-framework, dbcontext

Is there a significant difference between `.Find(id)` and `.Where(x = >x.Id == id)` that should compel me to use `.Find()` over `.Where()/.First()`?

I would imagine that `.Find()` would be more efficient but is it so much more efficient that I should avoid `.Where()/.First()`?

The reason I ask is that I am using a generic FakeDbSet in my tests to make it easy to implement fake results and so far I have found that I must inherit that class and provide a custom implementation of `.Find()` whereas if I write my code with `.Where()/.First()` I don't need to do that extra work.

Comment: Well you'd probably be better off comparing `Find` and `SingleOrDefault`, since `Where` returns collections.

Comment: True, although I always use .First or .FirstOrDefault.

Comment: @JimmyBosse you may want to consider the use of Single, for any situations where only 1 record should match.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The point is that `Find()` starts by searching in the local cache of the context and then, if no match, sends a query to the DB.

Call to `Where()` always sends a query to the DB.

With EF 4, I used to think that SQL generated by `Find()` was too complex and, in some cases, led to a performance issue. So I always use `Where()` even with EF 5. I should check the SQL generated by `Find()` with EF 5.

So on paper, `Find()` is better because it uses the cache.

Comment: +1. Find also doesn't have the overhead of visiting an expression tree, so it can hit the database faster, if it does hit the database. Where always goes through an `ExpressionVisitor`.

Comment: Can I not get incorrect data, due to the cache? Ie Db gets updated in the background?

Comment: Yes you can. You can also have concurrency acces problem on updating a record after retreiving it, or due to isolation level or... :)

Comment: Will it include uncommitted, added entities? If so, that's a significant thing to consider before using.

Comment: Can we get an updated the answer with some info on EF6/EF6Core if that changed?