# Master Page property and performance

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I'm using `ASP.NET Membership` and I have a table called `UserProfiles` which has a 1:1 relationship with `aspnet_Users` on `UserId` to store lots of extra fields. One of those fields is `OrganisationID` which will be used on pretty much every page in conjunction with regular roles for authorization purposes.

So I need to check the logged in user's OrganisationID very often. I don't want to use `Session` for this, I'd rather use the Membership cookie and call the database each time.

How much of a performance hit will it be to have the following property on the Master Page of the site:

```
public UserProfile loggedInUser
{
    get
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            if (Membership.GetUser() != null)
            {
                Guid userId = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
                using (var db = new DatabaseContext())
                {
                    return db.UserProfiles.Where(l => l.UserId == userId).FirstOrDefault();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The site isn't massive and the traffic won't be massive. Is this an OK approach considering?

Answer (score 0):

You could use .Find instead of .Where, which is, in general, [a better approach when getting a single entity by it's primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16966213/entity-framework-find-vs-where) (like your example).

I doubt it will make any difference though since you are creating a new context each time. If it were me, I'd probably try to inject the DbContext via dependency injection (using a per webrequest lifetime or similar) and then using Find. This way, if you use this property multiple times it will be much less of an overhead.

I'm curious, why don't you want to use a session variable for this? Are you concerned about increasing the size of the session too much? As you state, this is not a massive site and this is a per user model.

Comment: Appreciate the insights. I'll fiddle and come back a bit later. I just don't trust Session - use it as a last resort usually - got nothing to do with the size of it.