# ToList and Find implementation

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have this code.

```
var menucategories = db.Menus.Where(m => m.Language.lang_code == lang && m.published == 1).OrderBy(m => m.ordering).ToList();
```

With this code here I want to get all available menu types and to import into the DBContext memory.

```
db.MenuTypes.ToList();

foreach (var item in menucategories)
{
    if (item.published == 1)
    {
        //Search into the DBContext memory for the MenuTypes
        var view = db.MenuTypes.Find(item.menu_type_fk_id);
         ....
```

In this foreach loop I use `db.MenuTypes.Find(item.menu_type_fk_id)` statement. my question is, does this `Find` method will make round trip to the Database or will search into the DBContext memory?

Comment: Read Something about IQueryable and IEnumerable differences...http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/35b74da4-3dd0-4c96-83df-17bc496e4b8e/when-do-we-use-iqueryable-or-ienumerable-or-tolist?forum=adodotnetentityframework

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework Find vs. Where](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16966213/entity-framework-find-vs-where)

Comment: based on your code, it seems your all code belongs to same action or same method, so you can put menuTypes=db.MenuTypes.ToList(), and then replace var view=db.MenuTypes.Find(item.menu_type_fk_id) by var view=menuTypes.Find(item.menu_type_fk_id) and then it will not round trip to database.

Comment: Or like this. Search from Local.

var menucategories = db.Menus.Where(m => m.Language.lang_code == lang && m.published == 1).OrderBy(m => m.ordering).ToList();

            //Load all of the menu types to the DBContext memory
           db.MenuTypes.Load();

            foreach (var item in menucategories)
            {
                if (item.published == 1)
                {
                    //Search into the DBContext memory for the MenuTypes
                    var view = db.MenuTypes.Local.Where(m => m.menu_type_id == item.menu_type_fk_id).Single();
.........

Answer (score 2):

You can read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418(v=vs.113).aspx):

> `DbSet<TEntity>.Find:` Finds an entity with the given primary key values. **If an entity with the given primary key values exists in the context, then it is returned immediately without making a request to the store.** Otherwise, a request is made to the store for an entity with the given primary key values and this entity, if found, is attached to the context and returned. If no entity is found in the context or the store, then null is returned.

According to this if you load the records into memory before using `Find` method, the `Find` method will return the records from the cache otherwise it will send a query to db. You can also easily test this using `Sql Profiler`. Put a breakpoint on the line you call `Find` method then see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

**Find** looks in the stateManager...**(context) first, if not found, looks in store...**
2 clicks with resharper.  docu consistent with code ;-)

```
public TEntity Find(params object[] keyValues)
{
  this.InternalContext.ObjectContext.AsyncMonitor.EnsureNotEntered();
  this.InternalContext.DetectChanges(false);
  WrappedEntityKey key = new WrappedEntityKey(this.EntitySet, this.EntitySetName, keyValues, "keyValues");
  object obj = this.FindInStateManager(key) ?? this.FindInStore(key, "keyValues");
  if (obj != null && !(obj is TEntity))
    throw Error.DbSet_WrongEntityTypeFound((object) obj.GetType().Name, (object) typeof (TEntity).Name);
  else
    return (TEntity) obj;
}


/// <summary>
/// Finds an entity with the given primary key values.
///             If an entity with the given primary key values exists in the context, then it is
///             returned immediately without making a request to the store.  Otherwise, a request
///             is made to the store for an entity with the given primary key values and this entity,
///             if found, is attached to the context and returned.  If no entity is found in the
///             context or the store, then null is returned.
/// 
/// </summary>
/// 
/// <remarks>
/// The ordering of composite key values is as defined in the EDM, which is in turn as defined in
///             the designer, by the Code First fluent API, or by the DataMember attribute.
/// 
/// </remarks>
/// <param name="keyValues">The values of the primary key for the entity to be found. </param>
/// <returns>
/// The entity found, or null.
/// </returns>
/// <exception cref="T:System.InvalidOperationException">Thrown if multiple entities exist in the context with the primary key values given.</exception><exception cref="T:System.InvalidOperationException">Thrown if the type of entity is not part of the data model for this context.</exception><exception cref="T:System.InvalidOperationException">Thrown if the types of the key values do not match the types of the key values for the entity type to be found.</exception><exception cref="T:System.InvalidOperationException">Thrown if the context has been disposed.</exception>
public virtual TEntity Find(params object[] keyValues)
{
  return this.GetInternalSetWithCheck("Find").Find(keyValues);
}
```