# Entity Framework Core: How to IgnoreQueryFilters for DbSet Find method

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am using Global Query Filters but do not want to apply it on DbSet `.Find` method. I can not use `.IgnoreQueryFilters` because it returns `IQueryable`. Also I do not want use `.FirstOrDefault` due to [performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16966213/entity-framework-find-vs-where) reasons.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: In EF Core `Where` with `FirstOrDefault` is faster than `Find` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created more generic approach based on **dropoutcoder** solution. It does not require that DbSet has primary key with strict `Id` name. It still has only one key restriction but it suits me well.

```
public static class DataContextProviderExtensions
{
    public static T FindWithIgnoreQueryFilters<T, TValue>(this DataContextProvider context, TValue id) where T : class, new()
    {
        var expr = GetByIdExpression<T, TValue>(context, id);

        return context.Set<T>().Local.SingleOrDefault(expr.Compile())
            ?? context.Set<T>().IgnoreQueryFilters().SingleOrDefault(expr);
    }

    private static Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetByIdExpression<T, TValue>(DataContextProvider context, TValue id) where T : class, new()
    {
        var keys = context.GetEntityKeys<T>().ToArray();
        if (keys.Length != 1)
            throw new Exception("GetByIdExpression works only with Entity which has one primary key column.");

        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");
        var exp = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
            Expression.Equal(
                Expression.Property(param, keys[0]),
                ExpressionClosureFactory.GetField(id)
            ),
            param
        );
        return exp;
    }
}

internal class ExpressionClosureFactory
{
    public static MemberExpression GetField<TValue>(TValue value)
    {
        var closure = new ExpressionClosureField<TValue>
        {
            ValueProperty = value
        };

        return Expression.Field(Expression.Constant(closure), "ValueProperty");
    }

    class ExpressionClosureField<T>
    {
        public T ValueProperty;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create 'Find' extension method for `IDbSet<T>` where you can "simulate" original `Find` method lookup flow.

```
public static async Task<T> FindAsync<T>(this IDbSet<T> source, Expression<Func<TSource,bool>> predicate)
    where T : class, new()
{
    // parameters validation if needed

    return
        source.Local.SingleOrDefault(predicate)
        ?? await source.IgnoreQueryFilters().SingleOrDefaultAsync(predicate);//.ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

I didn't test it, but might work just fine.

In case you have some common table key convention you can even go for more generic extension method.

```
public static async Task<T> FindAsync<T, TKey>(this IDbSet<T> source, TKey id)
    where T : class, new()
    where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
{
    // parameters validation if needed

    return
        source.Local.SingleOrDefault(e => e.Id == id)
        ?? await source.IgnoreQueryFilters().SingleOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == id);//.ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It helps. But I still need more generic solution so I created my own based on your answer. Thanks.